# How to complete my proof on $a \mid c$, $b \mid c$ and $HCF(a,b)=1 \implies ab \mid c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

> > How to complete my proof on $a \mid c$, $b \mid c$ and $HCF(a,b)=1 \implies ab \mid c$

My effort:

Since $a,b$ both divides $c$, we have for some integers $m,n$ $$c=am,c=bn \implies c^2=abmn \implies ab \mid c^2----(*)$$

Now on the contrary let us assume that $ab \nmid c$, so we have by division lemma $$c=abq+R, 0 <R<ab $$

Then squaring we get $$c^2=abq_1+R^2---(**)$$

Now from $(*)$, we should have $$R^2=abp, \: p \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Now I am unsure how to arrive at a contradiction.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is HCF? Do you mean the greatest common divisor?

Comment: @5xum I thought it was greatest common *divisor*

Comment: Its $GCD$ alternatively called as $HCF$

Comment: This is a very standard fact about divisibility and GCD, there is a lot of proofs of this on the Internet. Do you need to prove it exactly this way?

Comment: @Aig Yeah, typo

Comment: Can you use Bezout's Lemma?

Comment: After $c=am$, and knowing that $HCF(a, b) = 1$ you can deduce from $b|c$ that $b|m$.

Comment: Yes I am curious to know, how to continue in that way without Bezout's? I have already seen MSE forums on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that if $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $ab\mid c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315316/prove-that-if-a-mid-c-and-b-mid-c-with-gcda-b-1-then-ab-mid-c) Or this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017556 Or simply: if $b\mid am$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $b\mid m$ hence $ab\mid am=c$.

Comment: @JMP How do you derive this? It’s rather $R^2\equiv 0 \pmod {ab}$.

Comment: @Aig; true; yet another wild goose chase!

Comment: Try if $a|c,b|c$ then $LCM(a,b)|c$. As $GCD(a,b)=1$, we have $ab|c$.